# a simple Ruta annotator

Tags: uima, ruta

I just started with Ruta and I would like to write a rule that will work like this:

it will try to match a word e.g. XYZ and when it hits it, it will then assign the text that comes before to the Annotator CompanyDetails.

For example :

This is a paragraph that contains the phrase we are interested in, which follows the sentence. LL, Inc. a Delaware limited liability company (XYZ).

After running the script the annotator CompanyDetails will contain the string:
LL, Inc. a Delaware limited liability company

Comment: Hi Renaud,
So far, I have tried a couple of tricks, that didn't work, and I am thinking of trying something like this:

AnnotatorAtTheBeginingOfParagraph PM? ANY+?{-> MARK(CompanyDetails)} CompanyDetails;   but since this not that simple I would like to hear from more experienced people before I go on.

Comment: I added an example in the answer, which rather refers to a sentence then to a paragraph, but that should be easily exchangable if really paragraph are needed. Let me know if you have problems with the syntax of the exemplary rules. I used rather entangled elements and haven't added too much comments.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean annotation of the type 'CompanyDetails' when you talk about annotator 'CompanyDetails'.

There are many (really many) different ways to solve this task. Here's one example that applies some helper rules:

```
DECLARE Annotation CompanyDetails (STRING context);
DECLARE Sentence, XYZ;

// just to get a running example with simple sentences
PERIOD #{-> Sentence} PERIOD;
#{-> Sentence} PERIOD;
"XYZ" -> XYZ; // should be done in a dictionary

// the actual rule
STRING s;
Sentence{-> MATCHEDTEXT(s)}->{XYZ{-> CREATE(CompanyDetails, "context" = s)};};
```

This example stores the string of the complete sentence in the feature. The rule matches on all sentences and stores the covered text in the variable ´s´. Then, the content of the sentence is investigated: An inlined rule tries to match on XYZ, creates an annotation of the type `CompanyDetails`, and assigns the value of the variable to the feature named `context`. I would rather store an annotation instead of a string since you could still get the string with getCoveredText(). If you just need the tokens before XYZ in the sentence, the you could do something like that (with an annotation instead of a string this time):

```
DECLARE Annotation CompanyDetails (Annotation context);
DECLARE Sentence, XYZ, Context;

// just to get a running example with simple sentences
PERIOD #{-> Sentence} PERIOD;
#{-> Sentence} PERIOD;
"XYZ" -> XYZ;

// the actual rule
Sentence->{ #{-> Context} SPECIAL? @XYZ{-> GATHER(CompanyDetails, "context" = 1)};};
```

Comment: I used UIMA Ruta 2.2.0 when running the examples, but that should not make a difference.